# Labelling problem for Shapefile with Indic Fonts

Tags: qgis, unicode

On my computer (Ubuntu 14.10, 64 bit), I am using QGIS 2.6.

I have a shapefile, where the names of the features are written in Indic Script (using Google Transliterate). When I wish to label them, the labels appear as `???????` even if I use a Unicode font like (Lucida Sans Unicode).

I created the shapefile as a ISO-8859-1 type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1, I don't see any support for Indian font characters.

I suggest to create a shapefile in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding, which is able to display all characters of the world that are defined by unicode correctly.

If you load the file into QGIS, make sure the encoding is set to `UTF-8` and not to `System` (which varies depending on the locale of your computer).